# React components make inheritance through Compositon

Tags: reactjs

i dont understand how to make inheritance make through Compositon
for example we have a simple `Clock` component:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then we want to make another Clock Component `HappyClock` and  it have same logic but different render method:

```
class HappyClock extends Clock {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, Happy world!</h1>
        <h2>It is Happy {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()} Time.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

how i can do it through composition if we want to have many different Clocks and same logic

Comment: Composition is not a mechanism of inheritance. So you cannot "inherit through composition". Ideally you would separate logic and representation, so that "the logic" was not part of any component at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pure components which renders what you already have in your render methods.

For example:

```
class ClockDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
       super(props);
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <div>
         <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>
         <h2>{this.props.displayText}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use this component in the Clock component.